# Windows share is not accessible from time to time

Tags: windows-7, centos, mount, network-shares, cifs

I have a CentOS box having a share mounted from local NAS (Synology) and a share mounted from a Windows Server 2012 (no utilities, plain standard share AFAIK). There's a script that does backups every night.

So far there were absolutely no issues with the NAS, however the Windows share is becoming not accessible from time to time (not sure of the steps to reproduce the issue since it happens once every 1,2 or 3 days in a random fashion).

Fstab entry to mount the shares:

```
//nas/backup              /mnt/backup           cifs uid=504,username=uname,dom=dom,password=pword,iocharset=utf8,noperm,rw 0 0
//192.168.178.202/Trinity /mnt/trinity          cifs uid=504,username=uname,dom=dom,password=pword,iocharset=utf8,noperm,ro 0 0
```

In dmesg I get an error:

```
CIFS VFS: Server 192.168.178.202 has not responded in 300 seconds. Reconnecting...
```

To which I found [this](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8134) bug report which doesn't clearly indicate the reason for the bug and ways to resolve it.

I tried adding a cron job like this 5 mins before the share is accessed by a backup script:

```
55 3 * * * mount -o remount,ro /mnt/trinity
```

but it didn't work. Any ideas and/or suggestions are welcome!

**P.S:** I sense that this might come from Windows end, but am not anywhere close to being Windows expert.

Comment: Curious why someone downvoted this?  Seems like a pretty solid question to me, with some good work effort put in before asking here.  Shouldn't we encourage stuff like this?  One suggestion OP: You may want to look into using a `credentials` file instead of putting everything hardcoded into `fstab`.  `fstab` can be read by everyone, you could limit permissions to a creds file. The Ubundu docs are a pretty solid [resource](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently#Mount_password_protected_network_folders) for this, if interested.

Comment: Please, comment about reasons why you down vote this question. Thank you.

Comment: @nerdwaller, thanks for the suggestion regarding creds file, but this server is there for a single purpose which is carried out by one user. Thus that issue is off the table. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what the actual reason is but a simple ls cron job resolved it. The job is executed 1 min before the backup script.

```
58 3 * * * ls -al /mnt/trinity > /home/backup/share-list.txt
```

Unless an actual solution comes up this workaround answer is gonna stay around.